# If $a_n>0$ and $ \displaystyle \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \leq 1 + \frac{1}{n^2}$ and $\displaystyle \{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \} \not\to 1$ then $a_n \to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

> Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of positive real numbers and for
>   $n \geq1$ we have:
>
> $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \leq 1 + \frac{1}{n^2}$$
>
> Moreover, the sequence $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to
> > \infty}\{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \} \neq1$. Show that:
>
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$$

Intuitively I understand what's going on. As $n$ gets larger, the sequence starts to behave more and more like a decreasing sequence because we have $\displaystyle \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \leq 1 + \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Moreover, the rate that $a_n$ decreases never gets slower because $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to
> \infty}\{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \} \neq1$.

Since $a_n>0$, after some large $N$ if we neglect the possible oscillations of $a_n$ the sequence keeps decreasing and the decreasing rate never gets slower, therefore it must eventually tend to zero.

The problem is that I don't know how I should formalize this argument. I spent some half an hour thinking about this, playing with inequalities, but I made no meaningful progress.

Comment: Show that limit of the quotient is *less* than one (i.e. that it cannot be greater than 1), and use standard argument to bound the sequence by geometric sequence, convergent to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\le1.
$$
Since $a_{n+1}/a_n\not\to1$, we must have
$$
0\le\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1.
$$
This implies tha there exists a subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ converging to $0$.

Next, observe that for all $m\ge1$
$$
a_{n+m}\le\Bigl(1+\frac{1}{(n+m)^2}\Bigr)\dotsb\Bigl(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\Bigr)\,a_n\le C\,a_n,
$$
where
$$
C=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\Bigl(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\Bigr).
$$
It now follows that the whole sequence $a_n$ converges to $0$.

Comment: Would you please explain why $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\le1$? Why $0\le\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$? And how did you come up with the third inequality? I mean what was your motivation? I'm sorry if I ask too many questions, I'm just confused because I haven't worked with $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ before.

Comment: For the $\limsup$ observe that $1+1/n^2\to1$. If $\liminf=\limsup$ then the limit exists and equals the common value.

Comment: OK, Thanks. And If I prove $a_{n+m}\le\Bigl(1+\frac{1}{(n+m)^2}\Bigr)\dotsb\Bigl(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\Bigr)\,a_n\le C\,a_n$, how does that imply that the whole sequence goes to $0$?

Comment: If $n_k<m<n_{k+1}$ then $a_m\le C\,a_{n_k}$.